# Using opacity map with principle shader and another color map

Tags: shaders, transparency

I am trying to mix a color map and an opacity map for a flower to a principled shader, but can't seem to figure it out. I have tried various ways, but doesn't work, will appreciate any help here.

[image: opacity map]

[image: color map]

[image: my nodes]

Comment: What if you plug the black and white image into the last mix node factor?

Comment: ah! Thanks, yeah, non need for the extra mix nodes. Just using the image for the factor did it. I tried using it the alpha of that as a factor initially. Thanks again!

Comment: Please create an answer explaining the fix and mark it as correct so that the question appears as answered (or resolve/remove the question). :)

Comment: I like Uncle Snail's suggestion. I am interested in screenshot of solution, if it is possible with you. For study purpose only, I am collecting photos of node compositing for scrapbooks as in link here. Credits are given. https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1MO11ucFLnwKzxjPKmLy4dfqMlQjJR1S9wHt1yB61Eqg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go - I plug the black and white image into the mix factor of the mix shader as a way to define where the transparency shader will take effect.
[image]