# Using an opacity map with the Principled BDSF?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, transparency, eevee-render-engine

I have baked a set of maps in Substance (making trim sheets) and would like to plug them back in in Blender, incl roughness, metal, normals etc. I would like to have those, my base colour map as well as an opacity map. Base colour map and opacity maps are below.

[image: base colour map]
[image: opacity map]

I have seen some solutions ([link to other thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131095/using-opacity-map-with-principle-shader-and-another-color-map)) for having a node setup that does not include BDSF, but the outcome is missing all detail from the other maps, see below two image examples.

[image]
[image]

I am wanting to achieve the opacity whilst not compromising on the other maps, below is the node set up atm. I have blend mode set to Alpha Blend.

[image]
[image]

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Ali

Comment: Just substitute the Diffuse node with its texture with the Principled shader with all its inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plug the opacity texture into the alpha socket of the *Principled BSDF* you should get the desired look.

[image]